# How to find and draw outer line of image in OpenCV?

Tags: android, image, opencv, counter

[image]

As given in images when I process image (BEFORE) then I need its outer borders and draw red color line (Like AFTER image) in OpenCV android.

Comment: "Tanks in advanced." actually made my day! :) Now seriously, what stops you from searching for `android image outline`? I guess you won't even need to use OpenCV.

Comment: Actually after process this image i need to get full borders coordinates.

Comment: I'd try this algorithm (which should work, at least theoretically): **1** - Make a copy of your bitmap and scale it some (4? 8? 16?) pixels bigger than the original one in both directions. **2** - Color transform it to a color of choice and optionally make it semi-transparent (I'd probably use a ColorMatrix for that). **3** - Over lay the original image against this transformed copy. I'm assuming the original bitmap being a transparent **PNG**, not a JPEG.

Comment: i want like this after get coordinates of image outer line , please check this:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006427/how-to-find-image-x-and-y-coordinates

Comment: Another (much simpler) approach would be to overlay the tank image to the tank silhoutte. Even simpler, just have 2 images: the tank WITH and WITHOUT outline. Then swap the images as needed.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this two images not give me the X,Y coordinates that i want,

Comment: The two images must have the same size. Therefore, the coordinates of one are the same of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical application of [cv::findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

A working example is provided in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html).

For your specific case you can do like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    Mat3b image;
    image = imread(argv[1], 1);  
    imshow ("Before", image);

    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, gray, 250, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    medianBlur(gray,gray, 3);
    gray = 255-gray;

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL , CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Scalar color = Scalar( 0, 0, 255 );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        drawContours(image, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }     
    imshow("After", image);
    return 0;
}
```

Which will give you this output:
[image: Example output]